# Flask Security giving routing error on security.register

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

While trying to link to Flask-Securities register view in my template with:

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('security.register') }}">Register</a></li>
```

I get a routing error

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'security.register'. Did you mean 'security.login' instead?
```

From what I've searched around for, setting the Flask Security config line "SECURITY_REGISTERABLE" to True should have fixed it, and yet it's set to True and I'm still getting this error...

I setup Flask Security in my models.py like so:

```
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

Comment: Show the code where you have [registered](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#sqlalchemy-application) flask-security with you flask app instance.

Comment: you should be using <li><a href="{{ url_for_security('register') }}">Register</a></li>

Comment: Complete code of your actual Flask app creation would be handy. It seems like you are missing some app config.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the exact same error after refactoring my app. In my new app.py I missed these config settings:

```
# More Flask Security settings
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTER_URL'] = '/admin/create_account'
app.config['SECURITY_LOGIN_URL'] = '/admin/login'
app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW'] = '/admin'
app.config['SECURITY_LOGOUT_URL'] = '/admin/logout'
app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGOUT_VIEW'] = '/admin'
app.config['SECURITY_RESET_URL'] = '/admin/reset'
app.config['SECURITY_CHANGE_URL'] = '/admin/change'
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = ['email', 'username']
```

The example above uses url endpoint inside my "Flask Admin" /admin

In your case i'm not exactly sure: by default flask security should be able to find the template folder and routes in the Flask Security package I think. The [quickstart](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html) docs don't mention any routes that you've you need to manually setup.

You'll also need a app config with something like this:

```
app.secret_key = 'SECRETSTUFF'
```

Probably an good idea to add explicit routes for the register page.

Answer (score -3):

The above error is occuring because there is no register() route available in the security blueprint or may be you have named register route as login() in your code. Plz recheck your code. By my little knowledge in flask-Security i think register view is enabled by default. To define the register view you just need to decorate the route using `@security.route('/register)`. I hope this is useful.